# creating dataframes from dict and appending them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a directory of files which I'm parsing into dictionaries with multiple key-value pair and I want to store each dictionary as a row in pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    dict1 = parseFileToDict(file)
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1, orient='columns')
    df_temp.set_index('name')
    df =  df.append(df_temp)
```

A sample output of the 'parseFileToDict()' looks like this,

```
d = {'name': 'foo', 'place': 'bar', 'dob': '22-11-1990'}
```

But I'm getting the following error while creating pandas dataframe from dictionary,

```
"ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"
```

Answer (score 1):

Create list of dicts first in loop:

```
L = []
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    dict1 = parseFileToDict(file)
    L.append(dict1)
```

Or in list comprehension:

```
L = [parseFileToDict(file) for file in os.listdir(directory)]
```

and then pass to `DataFrame` constructor if performance is important:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(L).set_index('name')
```

Comment: thanks for such a quick response. Is it always necessary to have values of dict as lists? Also will it keep the same orientation - i.e., keys of dictionary as column headers for dataframe?

Comment: @AmanSingh - If performance is important then yes, it is much faster